# setting itemListener of variable number of spinners

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner

```
    int numberofSpinner = TransportResult.Transfers.size();
    Spinner spin=null;
    for(int i=0;i<numberofSpinner;i++)
    {
        spin = new Spinner(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams p = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1);
        spinLayout.addView(spin,p);
        spin.setId(i);
        Transfer transfer = TransportResult.Transfers.get(i);
        ArrayList<CharSequence> s = new ArrayList<CharSequence>();
        for( Line l : transfer.TransferLine)
        {
            s.add(l.ShortName+" - "+Helper.FindTransportTypeText(l.LineType));
        }
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,s);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spin.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                  int position, long id) {
           if(parent.getId()==0){
       System.out.println("spin 1 is called");
               String str = (String)parent.getSelectedItem(); 
         }else if(parent.getId()==1){
       System.out.println("spin 2 is called");
               String str = (String)parent.getSelectedItem();  
     }
         }   
      public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

          }
      });
```

If the number of spinner is more than 1, only the last spinner is triggered. For example; i have 3 spinner on screen, when i select the item of first or second spinner, the listener is never triggered. Only the third spinner triggers the listener. How can i solve that?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

when you use more than one spinner then setid for each spinner `spin.setId(int)` .and you can check id in `OnItemSelected method.` Mind that when you set OnitemSelected first time onItemSelected is called.

```
 spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
              @Override
               public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {

                 if(parent.getId()==1){
             System.out.println("spin 1 is called");
                     String str = (String)parent.getSelectedItem(); 
               }else if(parent.getId()==2){
             System.out.println("spin 2 is called");
                     String str = (String)parent.getSelectedItem();  
           }
               }   
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

                }
            });
```

Comment: This is true when the number of spinner is 1. How can i do it when spinner number is different from "1"?

Comment: thank you for answer, but there is a new problem i edited my question

Comment: put  `spin.setOnItemSelectedListener()` inside for loop `for(int i=0;i<numberofSpinner;i++){spin.setOnItemSelectedListener()}`